# Disabling cache for website development

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [disabling chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

I am modifying a site's appearance (css modifications) but can't see the result on chrome because of annoying persistent cache. I tried shift+refresh but it doesn't work. how can i disable the cache temporarily or refresh the page in some way that the I could see the changes?

(google chrome by the way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a gear in the bottom right hand corner of the developer tools called settings that allows you to disable the cache.

On the pc you can open that by pressing ctrl+shift+i

or on the mac command+option+i